# Why is processing of filled JMS Queues (about 50.000 Messages) slower than processing fewer filled JMS Queues?

Tags: performance, jms

Why is processing of filled and persistent JMS Queues (about 50.000 Messages) slower than processing of fewer filled and persistant JMS Queues?

(I use a JMS Queue between two WepSphere ESB Mediation Flows. The one puts messages in the queue, the other flow gets messages out of it. When the JMS Queue is filled up to 50.000 Messages the processing gets very slow...)

Has anybody here the answer to my question? :)

Many thanks upfront!

Comment: It takes longer to process 50 000 messages than just a few ? Whats the actual question here ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to identify which part of your solution is slow. Your put could be slower as your putting persistent messages. As you might be aware persistent messages are written to disk, hence there could be delay.

Identify why the messages are piling up in the queue. Your consumer could be slow in processing messages.